# Position of suggested edit in the review queue

Tags: support, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

Is there a possibility to see which position my suggested edit has in the review queue?

Comment: Good question but in all honesty I'm not even sure if there is an order as such. Bare in mind that each reviewer would effectively have their own queue to work through and so the position of your suggested edit would be different for each reviewer.

Comment: @Bugs FYI, the phrase is "bear in mind". It's like [bear with me vs bare with me](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me). I like to have an open mind, but... ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan whoops, I got that wrong. Big time! Let's just move on quietly like it never happened :)

Comment: :0 We need urgently an edit function for comments! ;)

Comment: @Rekshino yes my 5 minutes is up unfortunately...so for 4 hours I've been giving off the wrong vibe...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, because there is no such thing as a position in the queue. Which item is shown to a reviewer is more or less random, at least for suggested edits (unlike the Close Vote queue which does have a certain [ordering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199912/295232)).

<sub>(source: if you have >2K reputation, visiting https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits a couple of times should convince you that it's random)</sub>

Comment: Really random? Can it be, that if there are ~300 entries in the queue and I put my suggestion in it, it will be reviewed next seconds? I see, that reviewer can skip an edit suggestion, and take the next one, but so far it is a queue, there are a position of an entry in it(at least in general queue), otherwise it is a bag or another container.

Comment: It's called a *queue*, but it's implementation is more like a *set* in that there's no FIFO or LIFO.

Comment: @Rekshino (almost) instant approval most likely happens through either the OP accepting the edit outright, or someone with >2k reputation seeing the edit pending (either in the queue or on the post itself) and using the "improve edit" option.

Comment: I don't think it's always random. If there are edits related to Swift or iOS (I've added these tags to my favorites), I see them first.

Comment: @FelixSFD that makes sense - I have no favourite tags so I don't know about this. I haven't seen a reference for this behaviour - this isn't caused by the filter by any chance? E.g. there seems to be no reply to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197051/295232) and related links.

Comment: @Glorfindel No, I've not set any filters in this queue. (BTW: I could reproduce it a few seconds ago. Opened the queue and the first post was about Swift)

Comment: @FelixSFD seems to work, at least for the first few Suggested Edits. Then I get other topics as well, even though there are more Suggested Edits within my favorite tag. The same behaviour is observed for Low Quality Posts, but not for the other queues. Interesting stuff!

Comment: I feel like the randomness is part of what is causing the review queue to constantly get full. Instead of suggestions right away getting seen by the next 3 (or more) reviewers, and then moving out of the queue, you end up with a lot of suggestions, each with 1 approve/reject, and it takes longer for a suggestion to get enough votes to be marked as approved or rejected.

Comment: @Rekshino: It's unlikely that it will be approved/rejected within a few seconds, but it's certainly possible that one person will review it soon. I've reviewed something 4 hours after it was approved, and then my next edit to be reviewed was something that had been submitted just seconds before. It really does seem to be mostly random.

Comment: @FelixSFD here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289860/213575

Comment: @Braiam Nice. Thanks! :-)